# Android App / ksoap2 - error when trying to get response from web-service

Tags: android-ksoap2

I am trying to connect to a web-service via ksoap2, and I am receiving the below error, on LogCat.

I/System.out(497): SoapFault - faultcode: 'S:Server' faultstring: 'For input string: ""' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@40567880

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Thanks in advance!

I have added below the part of code that I receive the error.. I am trying to retrieve the result via SoapPrimitive.

`try {
                   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport1 = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                   // Make the soap call.
                   androidHttpTransport1.call(SOAP_Levels, envelope1);

```
               SoapPrimitive result1 = (SoapPrimitive)envelope1.getResponse();`
```

Answer (score 0):

hope that's due to a large size file transfer , me to have the same problem while retrieving a large base64 string 
[How to retriving base64 strings(large image) from server to android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10850123/1389233)