# What's the best way to load the large size image from server to show on android device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-ksoap2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to retriving base64 strings(large image) from server to android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850123/how-to-retriving-base64-stringslarge-image-from-server-to-android)

## well i need some ideas about sending large size images from server and receiving the image on client side android phone ,

i tried with base64 string format but i am success with transfering small size images but the size more than 3000*3000 dimension returns null  while getting response from the server, Waiting for some good result from you guys ... to see coding  pls refer [How to retriving base64 strings(large image) from server to android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10850123/1389233)

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapPrimitive result =  (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

it returns null for large size image

Comment: Oh, the common solution is that create a background thread to download and UIthread to display that image. But I afraid It will leak your memory if you display too large image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try downloading the image directly (without Base64) from source on the web as below:

```
URL url = new URL("your_url_to_the_image");
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
```

And now save the *InputStream* to a `File` in cache on SD card. Afterwards refer to the saved file to load image.

For more info, read [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device).